# Cs-cart store import error

Tags: php, cs-cart

I was trying to import a **cscart3.0.4 MULTIVENDOR** store to **CS-Cart 4.2.2** using **store import** addon.

When i try to add path of store ,I am getting the following error.

```
"Error Import from this edition is not supported"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can not import **Multi-Vendor** store to **CS-Cart** and vice versa using the **Store import** tool, as these are two different editions.

You can import:

**CS-Cart Professional** v.2.2.4 - 3.0.6 >>> **CS-Cart** v.4.x.x

**CS-Cart Ultimate** v.3.0.1 - 3.0.6 >>> **CS-Cart** v.4.x.x

**CS-Cart Multi-Vendor** v.2.2.4 - 3.0.6 >>> **Multi-Vendor** v.4.x.x

Proof link: [kb.cs-cart.com/How-to-upgrade-with-store-import](http://kb.cs-cart.com/How-to-upgrade-with-store-import)

Use Multi-Vendor 4.2.x for your project or, I am afraid, you will have to transfer all data manually using **import/export** feature.